# Legend on pie chart matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, charts

I am trying to make the box for my legend smaller and placed in the upper left hand corner of my pie chart. So far I have:
pumsData = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('ss13hil.csv')

```
pieLabels = ['English Only','Spanish','Other Indo-European','Asian and Pacific Island Languages','Other']  
plt.pie(pumsData.HHL.value_counts())  
plt.axis('equal')  
plt.title('Household Languages')  
plt.legend(pieLabels,loc=2,borderpad=0.05)
```

the output for my chart is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbO4U.png

[image]

but I would like it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBxLz.png

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the font smaller?

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly create an axes instance as object instead of just using functions from the pyplot module, you can easier access plot properties. with `bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0.90)` as argument in `ax.legend()` you can shift the legend in the figure. Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pieLabels = ['English Only',
             'Spanish',
             'Other Indo-European',
             'Asian and Pacific Island Languages',
             'Other']  

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(4,4))

ax.pie([1,2,3,4,5], labels=pieLabels, labeldistance=9999999)
ax.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax.set_title('Household Languages')

handles, labels = ax.axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels, prop={'size':6},
          bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0.90),
          bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)

plt.show()
```

It should produce this figure: [image]

Comment: It makes me so happy to see other people suggesting tho OO api :)

Comment: @tcaswell it makes everything so much easier